# is there any way to fix this issue?

Tags: pi-2, camera, raspbian-stretch

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o image.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

i don't know how to solve for this. anyone could help?
(i have enabled the camera, gpu memory over 128MB. having raspberry pi3)

EDIT:
i am getting this error also ;

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o cam.jpg
 mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

Comment: Perhaps the camera has not been connected properly.  How about a photo of your connections?

Comment: Are you running the latest Raspbian Stretch fully updated?

Comment: @CoderMike yes i am using the latest version of raspbian stretch.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -o cam.jpg
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
 i am getting this error also

Comment: Did the camera ever work?  If not, it's probably because you do not have it connected properly.  You need to double check that.